# In DTD, how to let child element has the same name but different attribute type with parent?

Tags: xml, web, web-applications, dtd

For example:

```
<row>
   <row _id="1">......</row>
   <row _id="2">......</row>
</row>
```

How to use DTD to validate someting like that?
The structure of xml is not changeable.

Comment: Well, if you make the _id attribute implied then it does not get into your way for the outer row. Defining the content is more difficult and you have not spelled out the contents of the inner rows anyway. So far I think you might want to look at the XHTML DTD for `div` elements, they can be nested like you seem to want to nest your `row` elements, so you could follow the approach taken there.

Answer (score 2):

You say

> The structure of xml is not changeable.

but it's probably worth observing that that is in practice almost never the case.  You may not be able to persuade your data source (or perhaps the person who has set you an academic puzzle in language specification technologies) to switch to a different (and perhaps more rational, or at least more tractable) design, but that doesn't mean the structure of the XML cannot be changed.  One of the most useful techniques in XML processing is:  if your input is not in the form you'd like, transform it into the form you want before processing it.

The answer to your question depends on what you mean.

Literally, you ask whether it's possible in a DTD to "let" a child and parent of the same name have different attributes.  As Martin Honnen has already pointed out in a comment, the answer to that is "yes, just make all the attributes that occur on one but not both elements optional, and use them only where appropriate".

If however what you want is not just to enable an instance document of the form you specify but to enforce the rule that some 'row' elements (the parents) have no attributes but other 'row' elements (the children) have an ID attribute, perhaps required, then the answer is no, you cannot do that with DTDs.  DTDs have only one element type and only one element declaration per name, which means that in a DTD the parent 'row' and child 'row' instances are instance of the same element type, which has a declared set of possible attributes.  (The fact that you want the parent and the child to have different attributes is itself a pretty good proof that in your design they are different element types.  An observer might ask why you insist on calling two different element types by the same name.  Is the application not complicated enough, so that you have to make it more challenging by introducing pointless ambiguity into your markup?)

Other schema languages like XSD and RelaxNG both have local declarations, so that it's possible to have multiple element types of the same name.

Comment: It's also far of unheard of for an XML or SGML application with a DTD to have rules beyond those that can be described by that DTD. HTML would be a classic example, in that the DTDs allow for `<a>` inside `<a>`.